# How load multiple values into a multidimensional array in a single line

Tags: c#

Im trying

```
    SearchResultCollection src = searcher.FindAll();
    string[,] newLine = new string[src.Count, 4];

    foreach (SearchResult res in src)          
    {
        newLine[rowID, ] = new string[ , ] {"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"};  //Syntax error; value expected
```

but not luck ->  Syntax error; value expected on the line above

Comment: What are you trying to  accomplish?  It's not very clear - it appears that you're trying to build a 2D array, with 4 values in the first dimension and a rowID in the second dimension (wouldn't it make more sense to do it the otherway around?).  What your code would do (if it compiled) is reinitialize the array for each loop through the foreach.  Can you clarify what it is you want to accomplish?

Comment: Tim, basically I have to fill a 2D array according to the number of records on my query but may be I should create the array using the count property from my record set, string[,] newLine = new string[src.Count, 4];

Comment: I've added an answer.  It's not the most elegant solution, but it should fill your array based on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the OP's clarification, something like this might work.

```
string[ , ] newLine = new string[src.Count, 4];

for (int i = 0; i < src.Count; i++)
{
    newLine[i, 0] = value1;
    newLine[i, 1] = value2;
    newLine[i, 2] = value3;
    newLine[i, 3] = value4;

}
```

Maybe not the prettiest solution, but it'll do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

for a exsample...

```
        string[,] newLine = new string[src.Count, 4];

        for (int i = 0; i < newLine.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < newLine.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                newLine[i, j] = "....";
            }
        }
```